# Haskell scoping in nested function definitions using where

Tags: haskell, types, scope, type-mismatch

I have a problem with Haskell's scoping in `where` definitions. When I have the following function `f`, where I want to pass the `x` to the locally defined function `f1` without explicitely using it as a parameter, I get an error saying that the type of `x` is incompatible with the one in the output of `f1`, although it should be the same:

```
f :: Eq a => a -> [a]
f x = f1 x
    where
        f1 :: Eq a => a -> [a]
        f1 y = [ x, y ]
```

The error is the following:

```
    Couldn't match expected type `a1' against inferred type `a'
      `a1' is a rigid type variable bound by
           the type signature for `f1' at test.hs:4:11
      `a' is a rigid type variable bound by
          the type signature for `f' at test.hs:1:8
    In the expression: x
    In the expression: [x, y]
    In the definition of `f1': f1 y = [x, y]
Failed, modules loaded: none.
```

When I however pass the `x` as an additional parameter, as I did in the following code with the function `g`, it works fine:

```
g :: Eq a => a -> [a]
g x = g1 x x
    where
        g1 :: Eq a => a -> a -> [a]
        g1 x y = [ x, y ]
```

Is there a way to make the type `a` in `f` compatible to the type `a` (or `a1`) in `f1`?

Comment: Though it is very good practice to sugar your code with lot's of type signatures, except the extremely trivial parts, I don't see the reason to sugar locally scoped functions with them. It's obvious what the type signature is,  and for trivial functions like that, you lose more in readability than you gain.

Comment: Well, the actual function was more complex, I just reduced it to a simple example so my actual problem would become clear.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The problem with your code is the locally scoped f1 type signature. It specifies that f1 can take any type

`f1 :: Eq a => a -> [a]`

Even though this is a local function, you've generalized this function to be able to take a type that won't exist within f, whatever this function receives HAS to come from f, so the type signature is unnecessary.

Just remove the f1 type signature.

Edit: Read my post back to myself, it's a bit unclear. a in f1 is a parameterized type that can take anything, but the arguments passed to it are already bound in f. So this function can only receive what its parent function receives, the type signature you're giving it breaks that rule. Hope that's a little more clear.

Comment: Yeah, that works, thanks :) Although it still leaves a misgiving not being able to explicitely type the `f1` function (I'm coming from far stricter language), but well, as long as nothing breaks ;)

Comment: Poke: The problem here is that Haskell is being more type strict than you are expecting it to be. Your original type signature for 'f1' specified that the argument could be anything belonging to the 'Eq' typeclass, but the compiler correctly saw that the argument passed to 'f1' actually had to be exactly what was passed to 'f'. Removing the type signature for 'f1' does not loosen type strictness. Doing so only allows the compiler to infer typing for you.

Answer (score 23):

Dave is right above. Another way to think of it is that even though both of your type signatures refer to the variable `a`, it's not actually the same type variable. In the Haskell-prime notation, both signatures can be more explicitly written as:

`forall a . Eq a => a -> [a]`

meaning that for *both* functions, they can accept an argument of any type whatsoever (within Eq). This is obviously not the case here. In standard Haskell 98, the only option is to forgo the type signature for `f1`. But GHC (and others?) support [lexically scoped type variables](https://ghc.gitlab.haskell.org/ghc/doc/users_guide/exts/scoped_type_variables.html). So you could write

```
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}

f :: forall a. Eq a => a -> [a]
f x = f1 x
    where
        f1 :: a -> [a]
        f1 y = [ x, y ]
```

and that would work fine.