# Haskell: declaring a type for a "where" function that refers to variables in the higher level function

Tags: haskell

I was fooling around and defined a `for` function in Haskell as follows.

```
for :: (Ord i, Num i) => (i, i, i) -> b -> (i -> b -> b) -> b
for  (init, incr, end) initState bodyFn = for' (init, initState) bodyFn 

  where
  -- for' :: (Ord i, Num i) => (i, b) -> (i -> b -> b) -> b
  for' (index, state) bodyFn | if incr > 0 then index >= end else index <= end = state
  for' (index, state) bodyFn = for' (index + incr, bodyFn index state) bodyFn
```

It works fine.

```
> for (1, 1, 10) 0 (\i b -> i+b)
45
```

I'd like to declare the type for the `where` function. (As you can see, it's commented out.)  When I remove the comment marking I get this error message.

```
Couldn't match expected type ‘i1’ with actual type ‘i’
  ‘i’ is a rigid type variable bound by
    the type signature for:
      for :: forall i b.
             (Ord i, Num i) =>
             (i, i, i) -> b -> (i -> b -> b) -> b
    at while.hs:5:8
  ‘i1’ is a rigid type variable bound by
    the type signature for:
      for' :: forall i1 b1.
              (Ord i1, Num i1) =>
              (i1, b1) -> (i1 -> b1 -> b1) -> b1
    at while.hs:9:11
• In the second argument of ‘(>=)’, namely ‘end’
  In the expression: index >= end
  In the expression: if incr > 0 then index >= end else index <= end
• Relevant bindings include
    bodyFn :: i1 -> b1 -> b1 (bound at while.hs:10:23)
    index :: i1 (bound at while.hs:10:9)
    for' :: (i1, b1) -> (i1 -> b1 -> b1) -> b1 (bound at while.hs:10:3)
    bodyFn :: i -> b -> b (bound at while.hs:6:34)
    end :: i (bound at while.hs:6:19)
    incr :: i (bound at while.hs:6:13)
```

I'm guessing that the problem has to do with the fact that the `for'` function compares one of its variables with a variable from the `for` function -- and also adds one of its variables to a variables from the `for` function. They should be of the same type. Is there a way to say that? Or is there another way to declare the type of the `for'` function?

Thanks.

P.S. I know that I could declare the `for'` function as a top-level function and pass it the relevant variables, but I'm wondering if there is a way to write a valid declaration using this structure.

P.P.S Essentially the same question was asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1819575/haskell-scoping-in-nested-function-definitions-using-where), but the answer was to get rid of the declaration for the nested function. Any way to write one that will work?

Comment: The answer given to Mismatch of rigid type variables solved the problem. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to [jberryman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/176841/jberryman), the answer given to [Mismatch of rigid type variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38911523/mismatch-of-rigid-type-variables) solved the problem.  The following code works. (Note that `bodyFn` needn't be passed either.)

```
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}

for :: forall i b. (Ord i, Num i) => (i, i, i) -> b -> (i -> b -> b) -> b
for  (init, incr, end) initState bodyFn = for' (init, initState)  

  where
  for' :: (Ord i, Num i) => (i, b) -> b
  for' (index, state) | if incr > 0 then index >= end else index <= end = state
  for' (index, state) = for' (index + incr, bodyFn index state)
```

Comment: You don't need to write out `Ord i` and `Num i` again in `for'`.

Comment: Hopefully, the needless construction and deconstruction of tuples in `for'`will get optimized away. However, it is unidiomatic and the reader of the code will stumble upon it and ask itself: Why do we need to pass a tuple here?